# Does os.walk take advantage of the file type returned by the OS for efficiency?

Tags: python, optimization, directory

The [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) function returns separate lists for directories and files. The underlying OS calls on many common operating systems such as Windows and Linux return a file type or flag specifying whether each directory entry is a file or a directory; without this flag it's necessary to query the OS again for each returned filename. Does the code for `os.walk` make use of this information or does it throw it away as [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) does?

Comment: Does this actually matter in some real code of yours? If so, I can suggest a couple of alternatives (but you should probably change your question to ask how to optimize your program). If not, Martijn Pieters's answer is all you need.

Comment: @abarnert, doing a directory walk over a large directory on a network would certainly be enough of a load to notice the difference. I do not actually have a problem at hand, it just came up in the comments to another answer.

Comment: Yes, there are cases where it matters. And if you have such a case, there are alternatives you can use. But if you don't have such a case, just stick with `os.walk`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it does not.

Under the hood, `os.walk()` uses `os.listdir()` and `os.path.isdir()` to list files and directories separately. See the [source code of `walk()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/os.py#l209).

Specifically:

```
try:
    # Note that listdir and error are globals in this module due
    # to earlier import-*.
    names = listdir(top)
except error, err:
    if onerror is not None:
        onerror(err)
    return

dirs, nondirs = [], []
for name in names:
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
        dirs.append(name)
    else:
        nondirs.append(name)
```

where `listdir` and `isdir` are module globals for the `os.listdir()` and `os.path.isdir()` functions. It calls itself recursively for subdirs.

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn Pieters's answer explains, `os.walk` just uses `os.listdir` and `os.path.isdir`.

There's been some discussion on this a few times on the mailing lists, but no concrete suggestion for the stdlib has ever come out of it. There are various edge cases that make this less trivial than it seems. Also, if Python 3.4 or later grows a new `path` module, there's a good chance `os.walk` will just be replaced/deprecated rather than improved in place.

However, there are a number of third-party modules that you can use.

The simplest is probably Ben Hoyt's [`betterwalk`](https://github.com/benhoyt/betterwalk). I believe he's intending to get this on PyPI, and maybe even submit it for Python 3.4 or later, but at present you have to install it off github. `betterwalk` provides an `os.listdir` replacement called `iterdir_stat`, and a 90%-complete `os.walk` replacement built on top of it. On most POSIX systems, and Win32, it can usually avoid unnecessary `stat` calls. (There are some cases where it can't do as good a job as `fts (3)`/`nftw (3)`/`find (1)`, but at worst it just does some unnecessary calls, rather than failing. The parts that may not be complete, last I checked, are dealing with symlinks, and maybe error handling.)

There's also a nice wrapper around `fts` for POSIX systems, which is obviously ideal as far as performance goes on modern POSIX systems—but it has a different (better, in my opinion, but still different) interface, and doesn't support Windows or other platforms (or even older POSIX systems).

There are also about 30-odd "everything under the sun to do with paths" modules on PyPI and elsewhere, some of which have new `walk`-like functions.